# React Redux: Action Creators can almost all be async?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to write an application with React and Redux. I am using Redux Thunk because it has asynchronous operations in the application.
But it was something that confused my head. I notice that almost all of my Action Creators can be asynchronous. Is this an anti-pattern or a wrong approach?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong or an anti-pattern? If your actions need to go hit some external API then they can't not be async - if they weren't, I'd consider that more of an anti-pattern :)

Comment: Because 4 of the 6 methods can be asynchronous. I just got a little confused and wanted to ask. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux thunk is a [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) designed for the very purpose of dispatching async actions and using it to do exactly that is not an anti-pattern at all.

For the most part, you want your views to do nothing "smart" except `dispatch` Redux actions. These actions can be regular synchronous actions or async actions with side effects which are handled by Thunks, [sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), or [epics](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable).